# Designer Workflow: change document file extension upon upload

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-library, jquery, content-editor-web-part

So I would like to try to create a workflow on a library that simply checks to see if the file extension is anything other than .xml, and if it is, rename the Name (File Name) to the same value with the extension .xml. This should be a matter of simply storing the name in a variable, some expression to check it and update the field if need.

I would also use jquery approach in CEWP if needed, or that is more viable.

I am not sure where to begin with this and would appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sharepointaddict.blogspot.in/2012/10/adding-file-extensions-to-document.html

“SharePoint Designer Workflow Action: Retrieve the File Extension

Check this one it helps

Comment: still doesn't seem to be a way to change the extension though. errors out when you update the ItemName, or the Name & Path in any case